# Display text from .txt file generated by reg export

Tags: batch-file, text-files

I’m writing a script which should read the content of a file generated by reg export command to know Outlook data file path. Obviously I wanto to format the text to make a file without useless information like the first line “Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00” or the word “=dword:” in the generated file.
In for cycle I use echo to check if it’s working. Actually I have to change part of a line before recreate a  .txt file with  Outlook data file path.
My script works with any .txt file, but when it tries to read the file generated by reg export it shows nothing. This is the syntax of export command:

**reg export HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Search export.txt**

Here it is the script code:

```
@echo off
cls

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%G IN (export.txt) DO @echo %%G

pause
```

Thanks for your help.

Scorpion77

Comment: Why are you `Reg Export`ing to a file, if you do not want the file to contain much of the information it produces? Is that stage necessary if you can get the information you need in another way? What is the information you need? _We have not seen the text file you're wanting to parse or been made aware of the specific information you're wanting._

Answer (score 0):

A file created using `reg export` is unicode ([UTF-16 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16)), see the (truncated) [`hexdump.exe`](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/hexdump-for-windows.html) output:

```
reg export HKCU\Environment export.txt
hexdump -C export.txt
```

> ```
> 000000  ff fe 57 00 69 00 6e 00 64 00 6f 00 77 00 73 00  ..W.i.n.d.o.w.s.
> 000010  20 00 52 00 65 00 67 00 69 00 73 00 74 00 72 00   .R.e.g.i.s.t.r.
> 000020  79 00 20 00 45 00 64 00 69 00 74 00 6f 00 72 00  y. .E.d.i.t.o.r.
> 000030  20 00 56 00 65 00 72 00 73 00 69 00 6f 00 6e 00   .V.e.r.s.i.o.n.
> 000040  20 00 35 00 2e 00 30 00 30 00 0d 00 0a 00 0d 00   .5...0.0.......
> …
> ```

[*Files in unicode format cannot be read by the `FOR` command which expects `ASCII`. To convert the file format use the `TYPE` command*](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) as follows:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%G IN (`type export.txt`) DO @echo(%%G
```